# Apache Shiro + Authentication issues

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro for my Web Application and I have troubles getting it to work as intended.

What I need is the Authorization part of the Shiro Framework but I can not follow any of those guide as they are all different and I just cant get it to work in my application.

Here is what I want to use the Shiro Framework for:

- define the existing login.jsp as my login-page
- define a *.jsp page that is displayed when the login attempt was successfull
- when the login was not successfull, the user stays at login.jsp but is shown an Error-Message about his failed login attempt
- all other *.jsp pages exect login.jsp should not be accessible when the user is not logged in

Right now my application does it this way:

- login form `action` parameter calles login.java (servlet)
- on successfull login -> the page portal.jsp is displayed
- the page .../portal.jsp can be called without logging in -> This should not be possible in the final version of my application

the following things I figured out so far:

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
# define login page
authc.loginUrl = /SSP/login.jsp

# name of request parameter with username;
authc.usernameParam = username

# name of request parameter with password;
authc.passwordParam = password

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl  = /SSP/portal.jsp

[urls]
# enable authc filter for all application pages
/SSP/**=authc
```

shiro part of my web.xml looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

shiro part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The error I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configuration error. 
Specified object [authc] with property [loginUrl] without first defining that object's class.
Please first specify the class property first, e.g. myObject = fully_qualified_class_name and then define additional properties.
```

**EDIT :**

It seems this line in shiro.ini did the trick:

```
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
```

But now I have the problem, that the application doesn't use my own login class

login.java:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url = "/login.jsp";

    // Get Login credentials from Login form
    username = request.getParameter("username");
    password = request.getParameter("password");

    //SecurityManager securityManager = Startup.getSecurityManager();

    //2. Get the current Subject:
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    //3. Login:
    if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
        // create UsernamePasswordToken
        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("cn=" + username + ",ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com", password);
        try {
            currentUser.login(token);

            token.clear();
            url = "/portal.jsp";

            System.out.println("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() +"] logged succesfully");

            //4. Create User Session
            Session session = currentUser.getSession();

            // get user_id
            user_id = get_users_id(username);

            // create new object of User class 
            User new_user = new User(user_id, username);

            // Set HTTP Session Parameters
            session.setAttribute("user", username);
            session.setAttribute("user_id", user_id);
            session.setAttribute("obj_user", new_user);
            session.setAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);

        } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
            System.out.println("There is no user with username of " + token.getPrincipal());
        } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) {
            System.out.println("Password for account " + token.getPrincipal() + " was incorrect!");
        } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
            System.out.println("The account for username " + token.getPrincipal() + " is locked.  " + "Please contact your administrator to unlock it.");
        }
        // ... catch more exceptions here (maybe custom ones specific to your application?
        catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ae);
        }
        // Done, redirect User to applications main page
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } 
}
```

**How can I use my own class (see login.java snippet above) for authentication?**

**EDIT END**

Can anyone provide an example on how to:

- enable authorization
- enable page redirection after successful login attempt
- enable staying at login page but showing error message after failed login attempt
- make all other pages of the application only accessible if a user is logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the code of AuthenticatingFilter and created my own Filter so I can write `authc = com.mycompany.ssp.my_own_authFilter` dont know if that is how its supposed to be but it seems to work for now